# Case When Statement - Convert Output to Date Format

Tags: date, case, varchar, case-when

I have a case-when statement that returns the 15th of any month if my date field falls in that month.

```
 CASE WHEN (Date Field between date '2016-01-01 and date '2016-01-31') THEN '1/15/2016'
Else 'N/A'
End as New_Date_Field
```

The problem is that the value being returned (`1/15/2016`) in my New_Date_Field is not in date format, but rather `VARCHAR`. How can I convert this to a date format?

Updated:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEv8y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have date format, you have to convert it us convert or cast. When convert, we have to convert case and else to same format. In this case, ELSE will be null instead of 'N/A', because 'N/A' is not date format

```
CASE WHEN (DateField between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31') THEN convert(datetime,'1/15/2016',101)
Else NULL    End as New_Date_Field
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Syntax error, expected something like an 'END' keyword between the word 'convert' and '('.  Any ideas?

Comment: I included a screenshot in my original post with my query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's better to include some explanation of why this solves the problem (rather than having a code-only answer) so it's more useful to future readers.

Comment: @EJoshuaS  agree, context would be help here as well (as I'm learning SQL!). Let me know if you would be able to help me out, I'm still getting the error in my original post!

Comment: I still receive the error "Syntax error, expected something like an 'END' keywork between the word 'CONVERT' and '('.

Comment: Is datetime a function? It is not highlighting like the rest of the functions I'm using in my query. Also changed in my original query was 'N/A' to NULL - everything else is the same

Comment: Are you using MS SQL? It is working in my end for MS SQL. If you are using MY SQL, please see this link https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/convert.php and change the convert function to CONVERT(DateField, DATE)

Comment: In Oracle, will use To_Date like select to_date('2007-01-01 12:00:01 AM','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss pm') as dt from dual;